# Regular expressions to extract punctuations/characters

Tags: c#, regex

Hi guys I need a regex that only extracts punctuations/characters.

I have this so far :

```
[._^%$#!~@,-]+
```

but this works if there is at least 1 punctuations and still allows for any other char (digit or letter)

I need to to only allow punctuations/characters

Comment: @AndrasZoltan:
-.!@#$%^&*()_+=`~<>?':;[]{}|\

Comment: So is there any RegEx that I can use to allow for those characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try anchoring the regex to the start and the end of the string (unless you're using Multiline matching) - i.e. `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end:

`^[._^%$#!~@,-]+$`

Note - this does not endorse your actual pattern (I can't say whether this is matching all the 'special characters' you're talking about, but it will make it so that the entire string must be all 'special'.

Comment: `.` must be escaped: `\.` otherwise the above pattern matches anything.

Comment: @SinaIravanian `.` doesn't need to be escaped when it is inside a character class. See [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
^[\p{S}\p{P}]+$
```

`\p{S}` matches any symbol character, and `\p{P}` matches any punctuation.

Note that your pattern will not match all the symbols and punctuations not present in the list.

Comment: Note that the `DOT` used within `character class`, hence escape not needed at all.

Answer (score 0):

[^a-zA-Z0-9]* u can try something like this. Should NOT accept those chars, cba to writte all beside chars beside one u typed.

Comment: Totally wrong for unicode, and almost wrong for ASCII. For example it allows for whitespace characters, control characters, and so on.

Comment: as said, cba to write all shizzle he doesnt use

Answer (score 0):

```
\W
```

Matches any character that is not a word character (alphanumeric & underscore).